# What is 'weaving'?

Tags: spring, jpa, computer-science, terminology

I've seen this term when read about how Spring works and I've just read the article about JPA implementation performance and it has the next statistics:

```
EclipseLink                                                           3215 ms
(Run-time weaver - Spring ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver weaver  )
EclipseLink (Build-time weaving)                                      3571 ms
EclipseLink (No weaving)                                              3996 ms
```

So, could someone explain in plain English, what is *weaving*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Weaving is generating or editing code by directly modifying existing .class (byte-code) files.
This can occur at different points in the application life cycle.

1. Outside of JVM
   at compile time
   at packaging time
2. Inside a JVM
   at class load time.
   after a class has been loaded.

Spring Framework uses this for AOP functionality. Eclipselink uses weaving for lazy loading or change tracking.

Weaving described in [AOP Concepts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-introduction-defn) section of Spring Documentation

Answer (score 10):

From [here](http://www.java-forums.org/java-tips/6904-what-weaving-spring-framework.html):

> In Spring AOP makes it possible to modularize and separate logging, transaction like services and apply them declaratively to the components Hence programmer can focus on specific concerns. Aspects are wired into objects in the spring XML file in the way as JavaBean. This process is known as 'Weaving'.

Answer (score 3):

In nutshell, we could say

> Weaving is the process of applying the **Advices** to the **Target** objects
>   at given **pointcuts** to get the Proxy Objects.

Answer (score 1):

I‌ found this description useful:

Weaving: This is the process of inserting aspects into the application code at the
appropriate point. For compile-time AOP solutions, this weaving is generally done
at build time. Likewise, for runtime AOP solutions, the weaving process is executed
dynamically at runtime [using JDK‌ dynamic proxy and CGLIB proxy]. AspectJ supports another weaving mechanism called load-
time weaving (LTW), in which it intercepts the underlying JVM class loader and
provides weaving to the bytecode when it is being loaded by the class loader.

reference: [Pro Spring 5: An In-Depth Guide to the Spring Framework and Its Tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076FQ5KFK)

Answer (score 0):

Object-oriented software systems that are developed
using aspect-oriented programming techniques
consist of classes and aspects. Classes implement
the primary functionality of an application,
for example, managing stocks or calculating
insurance rates. Aspects, on the other hand, capture
technical concerns like persistence, failure handling,
communication, or process synchronization.

There are two ways in which classes and aspects
can be woven: static or dynamic.

Static weaving means to modify the source code of a class by inserting aspect-specic statements at
join points.In other
words: aspect code is inlined into classes. The
result is highly optimized woven code, whose execution
speed is comparable to that of code written
without using aspects.

Answer (score 0):

Weaving is a technique of manipulating the byte-code of compiled Java classes.

Ref: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/concepts/app_dev007.htm

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Weaving is the process of linking aspect with other application types or objects to create an advised object. Weaving can be done at compile time, load time or runtime. Spring AOP performs weaving at runtime.